# Not An Answer flag disputed. Why?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

When looking at a question I saw an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168705/4569506) which is not an answer at all.

It seems like a combination of a rant and a question. Oddly, it seems a lot of users have upvoted it (I suppose they agree with the expressed opinion?)

I flagged it, but my flag was disputed.

Why was it when the answer complies with one of the conditions for flagging (Asking a new question), as defined in the question [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4569506):

**EDIT**

I see somebody edited the answer, so that it is now **completely wrong**

The code in the answer was a demonstration of how the user wanted it to work, not how it actually works! This edit makes it seem like it actually works that way.

I'm not sure if I should rollback the edit, because the previous version is also wrong.

Comment: 3 reviewers in the VLQ clicked [Looks OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19610589) and in that queue they are right. That disputed your flag.

Comment: I assume @cerbrus is still around to chime in

Comment: Is it correct that you flagged as VLQ instead of NAA? Or is there a weird routing issue causing some flags to spill over in a different queue?

Comment: I flagged it as "Not an answer"

Comment: I'm not a mind reader so I can't tell why 3 users I've never heard of acted the way they did

Comment: I do know that the VLQ flag is to be used for utter garbage, not for answers that are wrong or go against your personal believes. If anything, use a custom flag in those cases to have a non-biased mod look at it.

Comment: @rene well, apparently no.

Comment: Honestly, I can imagine 3 users clicked _Looked OK_ pretty well. It was upvoted, and not plain NAA (link-only/spam/comment). I've never seen an upvoted audit in the VLQ queue where looks ok was not the right choice, so I can imagine there are robo-reviewers that think anything with multiple upvotes is OK (and honestly, those upvotes are the strangest thing about that answer, not the disputed flag).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth probably sharing their frustration that the author puts in the first 5 paragraph of the answer... or agreement that it should work like the example.

Comment: Why was this re-opened? That answer is an answer because it attempts to answer the question. As __explained in the duplicate__. Even if the answer is wrong, it can still be an attempt ast answering.

Comment: @NickA yeah that's a nice post. Unfortunately the orange should be NAA, but good luck getting the flag to pass :(

Comment: @NickA I meant the orange picture in the duplicate post you linked which is marked as "not an answer". I really wish that was indeed a valid example of NAA, but the usual "it smells like an answer so it is an attempt to answer" argument just overrules it. To me that is telling of how misunderstood the flag remains to this day.

Comment: @Gimby Ah, I see, I don't think that the orange is a very good representation of what NAA should be, the apples work as intended, but the orange less so, actual examples would be more effective. I had several NAA flags declined before I came to realise how strict the reviewers were, it really is a matter of, if there's an attempt, no matter how bad, it's still an answer

Answer (score 2):

Since it's been un-duped (the first dupe was perfectly fine), take a moment to read this post

[You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

The problem is that **there appears to be an answer in there**. It doesn't matter if it's good, bad or downright terrible. Not An Answer means there's no answer there (or the [answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)).

So the reviewers here got it right. If you disagree with the answer, downvote and comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - it doesn't appear as an answer at all. It (previously) contained a question, a rant followed by a piece of pseudo code describing how he wishes it would work. If you only skim it I understand why one would think so, but if you take your time and read the answer, it is clear that it is not even an attempt at an answer

Comment: @Daniel You don't have to write code to have an answer, pseudocode is just as acceptable as long as it portrays in a meaningful way how something could/should be done, it is not a reviewers job to review whether or not code is correct or indeed whether or not a concept would work at all. Their job is to check if what has been written is an *attempt* to answer the question at all. They said in their answer *"This example might not be the best... **But this approach enables me much more freedom and power when designing complex SPA architectures!**"*, this and the example constitutes an answer